# Find a basis for $U=\{p\in P_4(\mathbb{R}) : p''(6)=0\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for $U=\{p\in P_4(\mathbb{R}) : p''(6)=0\}$ where $P_4(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all polynomials with degree $4$ and coefficients from $\mathbb{R}$.

Apparently putting $p''(6)=0$ and finding a basis for the solution set for resulting linear equation with coefficients, then putting each basis solution into $p$ gives us a basis for $U$.  Why does this work exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Since $P_4(\mathbb{R})$ is a space of polynomials of degree 4, every element $p(x)$ of this vector space is given by
\begin{equation}
p(x) = a_4x^4+...+a_0\,, a_j\in\mathbb{R}\,.
\end{equation}
Just by counting, this is a five-dimensional vector space with basis $\{x^j\},j=0,...,4$. Now, $p''(6) = 0$ is a constraint on this polynomial space. Since this is one single constraint, it means that this constraint picks a four-dimensional subspace of the full polynomial space. So solving this equation will give you restrictions on one of the coefficients, namely
\begin{equation}
12 a_4 x^2 + 6 a_3x+2a_2|_{x=6} =  36(12) a_4+36 a_3+2a_2 = 0
\end{equation}
which just says that this subspace has $a_2$ constrained to be related to $a_3,a_4$ in this specific way (or $a_3$ in terms of $a_2,a_4$, or $a_4$ in terms of $a_2,a_3$).

Answer (score 0):

Because you've created a spanning set of linear independent polynomials. (i.e. they all have $p''(6)=0$, and there are enough of them). Any polynomial in $U$ will be a linear combination of the basis.