# How do we reason about extending the basis $(x^4-216x^2)$, $(x^3-18x^2)$, $x$, and $1$ to a basis of $P_4(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Consider the following problem from Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*

> (a) Let $U=\{p\in P_4(\mathbb{R}): p''(6)=0\}$. Find a basis of $U$.
>
> (b) Extend the basis in part (a) to a basis of $P_4(\mathbb{R})$

$P_4(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all polynomials of degree $\leq 4$ with coefficients in field $\mathbb{R}$.

This [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172751/find-a-basis-for-u-p-in-p-4-mathbbr-p6-0) has the solution for part (a), but **my question is about part (b)**.

Here is my solution to part (a)

$$p(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e\tag{1}$$

$$p'(x)=4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d\tag{2}$$

$$p''(x)=12ax^2+6bx+2c\tag{3}$$

$$p''(6)=(36\cdot 12)a+36b+2c=0 \implies -(216a+18b)=c\tag{4}$$

(4) represents a constraint on the coefficients of $p$. We can write $p$ as

$$p(x)=ax^4+bx^3-(216a+18b)x^2+dx+e\tag{5}$$

$$=a(x^4-216x^2)+b(x^3-18x^2)+dx+e\tag{6}$$

We have a linear combination of the four vectors $(x^4-216x^2)$, $(x^3-18x^2)$, $x$, and $1$.

We know they are linearly independent because equating (4) to $0$ immediately gives us $a=b=d=e=0$ as the only solution.

Thus, these vectors form a basis for $U$.

**Now, to part b) my question.**

How do we reason about identifying an extra vector to add to our basis so that it is a basis for $P_4(\mathbb{R})$?

I've tried $x^2$, $x^3$, and $x^4$ and they all work.

But it's not clear to me why exactly. I'm looking for a systematic way to reason about these vectors in polynomial vector spaces.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Servaes Any single vector out of $x^2$, $x^3$, and $x^4$ seems to work fine (easy to check that the resulting five vectors are l.i.). It's not clear to me, in the way that perhaps vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ would be, why these vectors work and what other vectors might work.

Comment: You can pick any polynomial such that $p''(6) \neq 0$. Check this!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah yes, of course!

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to see that
$$\left\{1,(x-6),(x-6)^3,(x-6)^4\right\}$$
is a basis for $U$. Throw in $(x-6)^2$ to get a basis for $P_4$